# How to fix CodeIgniter: Fatal error "Class 'CI_Model' not found"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried the suggestions in the other posts relating to this, but no joy. I'm trying to create a model in CodeIgniter that gets data from a database, but it's saying class CI_Model isn't found. My system path in the main index file is set correctly, and I have autoloaded this model in the autoload file, I cannot figure out the problem. I realise lots of the functions are the same, I haven't finished writing them yet and I'm using the first one as a placeholder.

**Edit: I updated all of these files with people's suggestions, and am still getting the same error.

**Model**

```
<?php

class Model_appointments extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getAppointments() 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('appointments');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function getActiveAppointments() 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('appointments');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function getCancelledAppointments() 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('appointments');
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function addAppointments() 
    {
        $this->name    = $_POST['name'];
        $this->details = $_POST['details'];
        $this->date    = time();

        $this->db->insert('appointments', $this);
    }
}

?>
```

**Front Controller**

```
<?php 

include 'application/controllers/databaseConnection.php';
include 'application/models/Model_appointments.php';

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Controller_name extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function  __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Model_appointments'); #load Model

        }
    }

class Front_controller {

    public function startFrontController() {

        $newDatabase = new Mydb('localhost', 'root', '', 'webinnovate');
    }
}

$newController = new Front_controller();
echo $newController->startFrontController();

$newAppointments = new Model_appointments();
$newAppointments->getAppointments();

?>
```

**Controller

```
<?php 

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'webinnovate';

class Mydb {

    public $query;
    public $myConnection;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $dbname) 
    {
        //establish connection
        $this->myConnection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what is the name of your controller ?

Comment: I have a controller called databaseConnection.php and a frontController as well, I'll add up the code for them.

Comment: you can select your DB in `config/database.php`

Comment: no clue if what you are doing will work at all but you are not calling the codeigniter controller like:  class Mydb extends CI_Controller {

Comment: if you are new to codeigniter try doing the tutorial in the ci docs to get a sense of how codeigniter does models, connecting to database, etc.

Comment: The controller worked before without extending CI_Controller. I'm working off some online lessons that aren't very explanatory. I'll definitely try the tutorial in the docs, thanks.

Comment: Stick with CodeIgniter naming convention which is first capital for classes: `Model_appointments.php`, `Mydb`, `Frontcontroller.php` etc. Also, your file name is `modelAppointments.php` and class is `Model_Appointments`. Those should be `Model_appointments.php` and `Model_appointments`.

Comment: I've changed all those, and now I'm back to the original error.

Comment: There is still lcfirst controllers' directory file. What is the reason you don't use CodeIgniter way of loading DB connection as Abdulla pointed in answer bellow? If you need more than one group /*default*/, you can set it [there](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html) too. I would suggest to read [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/) and [General Topics](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/index.html) particulary to set application right way.

Comment: I already had the database set in database.php. Forgot to mention that. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `config/database.php`

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root', # user name
    'password' => '', # password
    'database' => 'webinnovate', # Database name
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

In `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); #load database library
```

In your controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Controller_name extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function  __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('modelAppointments'); #load Model

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have done all that, I'm getting "No direct script access allowed" now.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me !
on my local windows system it was fine ,but when i migrated to Linux server (my hosting server )then it generate the same error:
it was due to case-sensitivity of Linux.


these are two deffrent words in linux:

'CI_Model'
'ci_model'

> so i suggest you to check your model name , if you are saving model
>   name to CI_model. and access it somewhere like "CI_Model".
>  here in Linux system
>   **CI_Model and CI_model are two different files.**

Comment: CI_Model is supposed to be a class within core\Model.php. Which it should know how to find automatically, apparently.

Comment: let's try place a class inside application/core/MY_model

then extend your model like abc_model extend my_model
it will generate error in linux while in window it would be fine .

Answer (score 0):

There're mistakes with a logic here. Let's try to understand what's wrong.

1. You need to understand what is OOP (because CodeIgniter is based on
   it)
2. You need to understand how CodeIgniter's architecture works (loading
   and using database class, for example)
3. Finally, You need to rewrite Your code.

I can't help You with the first two steps, but finally, at Your third step, **You will NOT**:

1. Use `include()` function in CodeIgniter's Controllers
2. Try to use `$this` as parameter for `$this->db->insert()`
3. Define variables for `__construct()` outside of the Class definition
4. Try to `echo` anything outside of Class, extended from CI_Controller

But **You WILL**:

1. Use multiple DB configuration
2. Use CI's Model for DB wrap
3. Load Your model as simple as $this->load->model()

Dear, Tanya Branagan, I know, that's not kind of answer You waited for, but You try to use the framework without attempt to understand how it works. Please, be patient and read at least about [CI's Controllers](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html), [CI's Models](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html) and [CI's Database Configuration](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html)

Comment: I realise that I don't understand it, that's why I'm asking for help. A lot of this code is taken from templates in the online lessons I'm using, the $this->db->insert() with $this as a parameter, for example. The lessons don't fully explain the principles. For example, they do not have any instructions about how to implement a database, other than to add it to database.php, which I have done. And I use OOP fine in C#, CodeIgniter is the only thing that's giving me trouble.

Comment: @TanyaBranagan ok. So.. `$this->` - is the pointer to current object(in PHP, not only in CI). `$this->db->insert($table,$data)` function expects at least 2 params: 1st is a string with MySQL's table, second is for array with data to insert with pairs key=>value, where key is a table's column name. You needn't to include anything, because CI uses `$this->load->` construction to load anything correctly. Also You'll not be able to use Your `$host`,`$username`, etc in `__constructor()` because of encapsulation. Encapsulation works same in most languages.

Comment: @TanyaBranagan Try to read http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html to get started with CI, it's the clearest explanation how CI works, I think. For now Your question is not about specific problem, but about a general question "How to use CI?". You can find many tutorials in Internet, but I suggest You to start from CI's manuals, they're really good. Have a nice day!

Comment: I've made several pages with CodeIgniter before though, and they worked fine, and even using them as a reference I can't get this to work, and I don't understand why, which is why I'm asking for help. I will go through the tutorial though.

Comment: Also, I used $host etc in the controller constructor in my last project and it worked. And also my college lessons told us to do that.

Comment: @TanyaBranagan Maybe You, after definition Your vars, call `$obj = new Mydb($host, $username, $password, $dbname);`? This way yes, it's possible to send Your vars to Class'es constructor, but You'll not be able to use them at Your methods inside the Class. For example, try to add method `function test(){echo $host;}` inside the Mydb and then call `$obj->test();`. You'll not get Your $host from _outside_. If You want to use them at Your methods, You need to read about getters and setters, define these vars inside the class and call them in methods as `$this->host`